# How to check that all javascript/css loaded correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find out a solution which will notify user if some resources did not loaded correctly.

Already I founded following methods:

1. For CSS I found example in Trello source:

   ```
   <div id="nocss"> 
     Your browser was unable to load all of Trello's resources. They may have been blocked by your firewall, proxy or browser configuration.
     <br>Press Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+Shift+R to have your browser try again. 
     <hr>
   </div>
   ```

   And in last downloaded CSS there is a following CSS:

   ```
   #nocss {
    display: none;
   }
   ```
2. For JS i founded following article: [The best way to load external JavaScript](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/28/the-best-way-to-load-external-javascript/), but I am not sure about it.

**UPDATE**

Small update: the best solution should work also with files from CDN, because they are the biggest problem. I had a site in which I added jquery and in companies behind the firewall it was blocked.

Comment: If you can't change the files loaded from cdn then maybe you want to use window.onload and check if specific variables where modified by the script e.g. jquery would modify (or set) the $ variable.

Comment: Have you tried `yepnope`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do pretty much the same with your javascript like you do with your css.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nojs").css("display","none");
}
```

This code uses jquery. If put into the beginning of your javascript file it hides a div like your css does once the javascript is loaded. (of course you need a `<div id="nojs">`)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add a class to the body for each successfully loaded JS file (in each JS file write code to add additional CSS class to the body element like so `$(document.body).addClass("SomeClass")`). Then simply check

```
if (!$(document.body).hasClass("ALL YOUR CLASSES")){
    $("nojs").show();
}
```

This should do the trick.

If you don't have access to the files and cannot modify them then why do something like the following:
`<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>` (Taken from HTML5 Boilerplate)

Comment: Don't you think that this will be tedious when it will be in maintenance mode?

Comment: This won't work for JS and CSS from CDN, I cannot modify them.

Comment: Oh, i was not sure if you had access to the files.. edited answer please check.. you may want to check like so and then instead of writing a new script tag just display the warning div..

Answer (score 1):

Rather than being dependent on any other method, can you use

```
window.onload=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

or

```
<body onload="SomeJavaScriptCode">
```

Above ones will only execute after loading all contents of your page. (onload is most often used within the  element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.).)